# Omission of "in" in the sentence?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

> He announced that the mission would be implemented **in** all districts.

Is it necessary to use *in*?
Is the sentence still grammatically correct, when *in* is omitted?

Comment: What's your justification for omitting it?

Comment: What is your understanding of the relationship **in meaning** between the implementing that’s going on here and the districts?

Comment: @DoneWithThis. For I know sometimes Preposition can be omitted but I don't know the rule "when to do?"

Comment: You *must* have a preposition there, but it doesn't have to be ***in***. For example, *He announced that the mission would be implemented **across** all districts.*

Comment: You could say "implemented all day," because *all day* is a set term, but not "all districts."

Comment: There isn't a rule for 'when a preposition can be omitted' - you just have to learn it case by case.

Comment: It's not clear how a **mission** can be **implemented**. How can a mission "be put into effect"?

Comment: In declined languages where *all districts* could be cast into an oblique case, there would be no need for a preposition, and speakers of those declined languages may be trying to translate word-for-word.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: With OP's adverbial ***all districts***, you *must* include a preposition. With your suggested ***all day***, you *can't* include a preposition. But with *[He said it] would be implemented **on Monday***, many native speakers (especially Americans) would be perfectly happy to omit the preposition: [***It will be implemented Monday.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22will+be+implemented+Monday%22)